# why do we need to foreUnwrap the dataType while creating an object? Swift 5

Tags: class, types, uilabel, swift5, xcode11

whenever I go to internet or check projects on online while creating any object in ViewController class I see an exclamation mark(!) at end of data type why is that? for example:@IBOutlet weak var Label:UILabel!
so why is that '!' mark or why are we force unwrapping it?
And also when I remove it , it gives an error ,  we can also write like this @IBOutlet weak var Label=UILabel()
so why don't we use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the things step by step to get an answer.

1. @IBOutlet: This is a property wrapper that tells Xcode to connect an element on the storyboard with the one in `.swift` file.
2. The `!` mark: This force-unwrap thing is recommended because when the `.swift` file needs the instance, it's sure to find the connected element in storyboard. We can also write @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel? In this case the instance `Label` would be optional.
3. @IBOutlet weak var Label=UILabel(): In this case the instance `Label's` value is overridden with `UILabel()` immediately after initialization. The `@IBOutlet weak var Label!` and `Label` after `Label = UILabel()` are not the same instances.

`@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel` is equivalent of writing `var label: UILabel`. Therefore the i-val does not have an initial value and Swift does not allow that. In Swift either you have to assign a value to a variable or make it optional/unwrapped to explicitly deal with nil values. And also when you unwrap the instance with `@IBOutlet`, you can use it with `?` later on like `label?.text = "Some text"`.

So, we are forced to use `!` or `?` for an outlet to explicitly make the variable optional as in for other variable declarations. And we don't use `= UILabel()` after declaration because it overrides the instance created from the Storyboard (initialized with an `NSCoder/Coder` from the nib).

Comment: hey @KoushikMudi , var mapView:MKMapView!
    
    override func loadView(){
        mapView = MKMapView()  } what about this code I can also write var mapVIew = MKMapView inside loadView , instead of declaring it outside the load view method (I found this code in a book)

Comment: Hey @YuvrajAgarkar This is definitely correct to write this way. but here you're not initializing the mapView from Storyboard. This will also be applicable to the UILabel example. If you do not connect the UILabel from storyboard, this is the way to initialize and use UIView classes in a .swift file.

Comment: Happy to help @YuvrajAgarkar